# How to have CSS animated DIVs start hidden and appear 1 by 1?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

The goal is that once the user scrolls and the red boxes come into view, the CSS animation is triggered.  It works pretty good, except that I was expecting all the boxes to start fully hidden and then the first box fades in, then the 2nd box fades in, then the 3rd, etc.  But they all start visible, then disappear real quick before fading in.

How would I get all 4 boxes to start invisible and then only appear once their respective fadein animation starts?

```js
;
(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
    return this.each(function(i, el) {
      function visPx() {
        var H = $(this).height(),
          r = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
          t = r.top,
          b = r.bottom;
        return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t > 0 ? H - t : (b < H ? b : H)));
      }
      visPx();
      $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
    });
  };
}(jQuery, window));


$(function() { // DOM is now ready
  $(".animateinview").inViewport(function(px) {
    if (px) $(this).addClass("triggeredCSS3");
  });
});
```

```css
.space {
  height: 800px;
}

.column {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fadeinfast.triggeredCSS3 {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein1.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein2.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein3.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein4.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein1 animateinview">

</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein2 animateinview">

</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein3 animateinview">

</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein4 animateinview">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` and set the initial opacity to 0. I updated the Fiddle to reflect the changes: https://jsfiddle.net/d27fwe5c/6/

What this does is that it halts the animation on the last frame. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

```js
;
(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
    return this.each(function(i, el) {
      function visPx() {
        var H = $(this).height(),
          r = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
          t = r.top,
          b = r.bottom;
        return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t > 0 ? H - t : (b < H ? b : H)));
      }
      visPx();
      $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
    });
  };
}(jQuery, window));


$(function() { // DOM is now ready
  $(".animateinview").inViewport(function(px) {
    if (px) $(this).addClass("triggeredCSS3");
  });
});
```

```css
.space {
  height: 800px;
}

.column {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeinfast.triggeredCSS3 {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein1.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein2.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein3.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.fadeinfast.fadein4.triggeredCSS3 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">
</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein1 animateinview">

</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein2 animateinview">

</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein3 animateinview">

</div>
<div class="column fadeinfast fadein4 animateinview">

</div>
```